# Can druid perform a nested query such that each contain one dimension and a list of associated dimensions?

Tags: druid

For instance, given this data:

```
{"timestamp": "2011-01-12T00:00:00.000Z", "ip": "1" "user": "abc" } 
{"timestamp": "2011-01-12T00:00:00.000Z", "ip": "1" "user": "def" } 
{"timestamp": "2011-01-12T00:00:00.000Z", "ip": "1" "user": "hgi" }
{"timestamp": "2011-01-12T00:00:00.000Z", "ip": "2" "user": "mno" }
{"timestamp": "2011-01-12T00:00:00.000Z", "ip": "2" "user": "qrs" } 
{"timestamp": "2011-01-12T00:00:00.000Z", "ip": "3" "user": "xyz" }
```

Is it possible to do an efficient query that returns

```
  {
    "timestamp": "...",
    "event": {
      "ip": 1,
      "user": ["abc", "def", "hgi"]
    },
  {
    "timestamp": "...",
    "event": {
      "ip": 2,
      "user": ["mno", "qrs"]
    },
  {
    "timestamp": "...",
    "event": {
      "ip": 3,
      "user": ["xyz"]
    }
```

And if so, is it possible to limit the results count of only the `user` list result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a druid groupBy Query you cannot apply a "sub-group" or "group_concat" function. These simply are not available. Druid will group your query by the fields which you select.

Of course you can group per `ip` and then count the number of rows or even the number of distinct users.